# C++ change bits per block of boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have one file that has a boost::dynamic_butset input. This file stores blocks in chunks of 8 bits. Then, it gets passed into a function in the file which I am allowed to edit. The problem is, I need to store the bits of this bitset into a vector of 16 bit integers instead of 8 bit ones.

I tried this

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<uint16_t> newInput (input);
```

But it says there is no matching function call because of the different types. How can I get this original bitset stored in a vector ?
The input bitset that I am using is absolutely enormous, so using a for loop to move everything is out of the question.

Comment: Can you expand on why a loop is "out of the question"? Ultimately, something somewhere is probably going to be doing this with a loop. It's only a question of how much abstraction you can get out of wrapping it with libraries. A [MCVE] would help. Did you read the `dynamic_bitset` documentation for inspiration?

Comment: Off topic: from the dynamic_bitset doc: "_This function is not a member function taking zero arguments and returning a string for a couple reasons. First, this version can be slighly more efficient because the string is not copied (due to being passed by value). Second, as a member function, to allow for flexibility with regards to the template parameters of basic_string, the member function would require explicit template parameters. Few C++ programmers are familiar with explicit template parameters, and some C++ compilers do not handle them properly."_ Wow, that is ... ancient!

Comment: BTW although I assume this is a school assignment, this is really not how dynamic_bitset is supposed to be used, which is probably why I'm finding no built-in mechanism to copy/move its contents into another dynamic_bitset of another block size. In real life, if given a dynamic_bitset with 8-bit blocks you'd just use those 8-bit blocks; it's not hard to treat it as one with 16-bit blocks with some basic arithmetic on access, though admittedly once you need shifting and masking that gets more complex. See, not what it's designed for!

Comment: It is, and it's extremely annoying that we are forced to use bitsets in this way. I'd rather use a stream. But, I can't use a for loop on the original bitset because it has 520 million bits. I can move these bits into a vector of bytes and use the loop on that, which is faster, but the vector of bytes still has 65,000,000 bytes in it. If I could store 16 bits at a time however, the vector would have 32 million bytes in it, which is still a lot but it will also help a lot with the compression algorithm I'm doing all of this for

Comment: Does your compression algorithm care whether the data is stored in a vector of `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`? If it doesn't, you can copy the data from the bitset into a `vector<uint8_t>` using the [`to_block_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range) function. You can then access the underlying data buffer (which is contiguous) using `vector::data`

Comment: It doesn't care, but it does run significantly slower when using 8 bit values. I tried the method you just mentioned, but the problem with that is it makes the same number of values, it just pads them all with 8 more zeroes. I want to reduce the number of elements in my vector. I can read in my bitset to a vector of integers of any size, but it will store the same numbers just with different zero padding. I  need to read it in a way where it actually groups 16 bits together and stores them as a much bigger number, not just a padded byte

Comment: I don't understand why you're seeing padding, did you insert into a `vector<uint16_t>` instead of `vector<uint8_t>`? See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f83013b2ff36edc3). If you must have a `vector<uint16_t>`, easiest is to loop over the bitset or copy into a `vector<uint8_t>` and loop over that, in both cases, you'll shift, OR and `push_back` into the `vector<uint16_t>`.

Comment: If you don't like either of those approaches, you could create a stateful type that satisfies [*OutputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) requirements and adds to a `vector<uint16_t>`. It'll need to handle odd and even elements differently. You can use that in conjunction with `to_block_range`, similar to how I use `back_inserter` in my example.